# How to rewrite a USB device software

Tags: usb

Lets say I have a device I can connect via USB port. How do I get it's software and re-write it to what I want to do with it? I've seen people plug in stuff such as Headsets and just do stuff, get the code and rewrite it. How do I do so?

Comment: This question is way too broad.  Someone could write 1000 words on this subject and there's a good chance it won't even get you 2% of the way done with your project.  Even if you told us specifically what device you are talking about (which you didn't), you'd also need to specify what software you are talking about, what steps you have taken to rewrite it, what step you are stuck on, and you'd probably need to provide a [mcve] showing your problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I dont think this question was broad at all dude, How do i rewrite the software in a USB device (not a usb storage or flashdrive)